# Why do `sudo` and `sudo -i` treat NOPASSWD differently?

Tags: sudo, sudoers

I have an account that needs to masquerade as other accounts seamlessly, like so:

```
manager$ sudo -u worker_A echo hello from worker A
hello from worker A
manager$ sudo -u worker_B echo hello from worker B
hello from worker B
```

So I put something like this in a file under `/etc/sudoers.d`:

```
manager ALL=worker_A,worker_B,worker_C NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This seems to work fine for the above commands.  However, in some instances the stuff I need to do as the `worker_*` accounts needs the whole login environment, i.e. I need to pass the `-i` / `--login` flag to sudo.  However, when I try this, I get a totally unexpected result:

```
manager$ sudo -u worker_A echo hello from worker A
hello from worker A
manager$ sudo -u worker_A -i echo hello from worker A
[sudo] password for manager:
```

**Questions:**

- What is going on here?
- How can I fix it?

(Note: I have changed the account names and simplified the contents of the sudoers file both to create a minimal example and to protect privacy.  Hopefully I haven't inadvertently made any typos or changed anything in the process.)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to log in as the other user, then you can't pass other commands (````echo````...) in the same line. You need to first log in (````sudo -i```` for root, ````sudo -u worker_A -i````, or ````sudo su worker_A````) and once you get the new shell with that user you can continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to preclude anyone spending time trying to figure this out and maybe help someone who runs into similar issues, there was an unrelated rule elsewhere that was being inherited by the `manager` account which conflicted with the existing one, resulting in unexpected behavior.

(In particular, the other rule was one allowing developers to become the `worker_*` accounts, but only if they specifically used the command `sudo -i -u worker_A` to get an interactive shell.)